# Help regarding What DBMS to use for interaction between android phone, server and database?

Tags: java, android, database, rdbms

I am looking for some guideance in terms of what database to use server(using servlets) side of my android application.

Further down the line i will setup a website that will need to access the information from with the database.

At the moment from what i know i can use hibernate for object mapping to RDBMS or i can use JDBC for interaction with a MySql Database.

Do you guys have any best practices for using either the above or a different system for interaction between servlet and database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get started quickly, you could use [AppInventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com), but if you want to build a backend yourself I suggest [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/download)(get ubuntu if you don't have it!). Its easy to learn, easy to install, and very user-friendly.

The server and database will be handled by the Ruby on Rails framework.

Answer (score 0):

Android application just acts as a client that makes request and accepts response from a Server. Server could be written using Servelets / JSP, ASP or PHP. As far as I know it doesn't matter to android client which database server is used at the server side as far as client is getting the response from the server.

Comment: i know but what would u reccomend for access to a database(mysql) from a servlet?